# JqGrid sort icons displaying incorrectly

Tags: jquery, html, css, jqgrid

I am working with jqGrid and am having issues with the ui aspect, the sorting icons in particular. It seems that there is some overflow from the span that contains the sorting icons so it cuts the top off.[image: Top sort icon]
This is an eample of what I mean. As you can see, the grey background is cut off from the top.
[image: Desc sort]
The descending Icon comes out fine however.
So my question is, is there a way I can remove this grey background from the sort icons? I would ideally like to replace the arrows and know how to do that. I am just lost as to removing the grey area.
As a side note, there is overlap on the icons too. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: What is "ui aspect"? Is it some jQuery UI Theme? You should provide a demo (in jsfiddle for example) which can be used to reproduce the problem. It's clear that you have some CSS conflicts, but to solve the problem one have to have the demo with the problem, examine it with respect of Developer Tools and only after it one can suggest the solution of the problem.

Comment: Hi Oleg. Thanks for taking the time to comment. When I said "ui aspect" I just meant the ui aspect of the jqgrid, not my actual implementation. I think I have come up with a solution using css/jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was messing around with jQuery and stumbled upon a solution for myself.

```
$('.ui-icon-triangle-1-n').css({'background-color':'transparent'});
```

removed the background from the ascending arrow, so I will be putting this into css form in my project.